# Batch file: Search for text and proceed on error

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

I've tried to write a batchfile, which would check it's own directory for other batch files and check these for a certain text. If the text is found, I want the program to jump to the end, otherwise copy itself into the found file. Here's how I tried:

```
    rem windowsisajoke
    for %%f in (*.bat) do (set A=%%f)
    set FILE=%A%
    set CONTENT=windowsisajoke
    findstr /i "%CONTENT%" %FILE% >NUL
    if errorlevel 0 goto end
    copy %0 %A%
    :end
```

Comment: Can you tell us what goes wrong? What errors did you get, what was the expected result, what is the actual result?

Comment: Purpose sounds malicious, but so does the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if errorlevel 0` actually means "if errorlevel is zero or greater". (I know - very intuitive...)

Either change your logic:

```
if errorlevel 1 copy %0 %A%
```

or use

```
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :end
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed I used %errorlevel% and it works fine!